# strange result by converting images to avi using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, avi

I am trying to convert a series of images to avi using matlab. The code is shown below.

aviobj = avifile(navi);

aviobj.Quality = 100;

%aviobj.Fps = 25;

aviobj.compression='None';

cola=0:1/255:1;

cola=[cola;cola;cola];%% grey scale image

cola=cola';

aviobj.colormap=cola;

for i=pfrom:pto

```
strImgName=Files(i).name;

    adata=imread(strImgName);

    figure;

    imshow(adata); % the loading image seems good

     aviobj = addframe(aviobj,uint8(adata));
```

end

aviobj=close(aviobj);

The resulting avi is strange. I attached one image and one frame of the avi as follows. What is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is has something to do with the colormap. `imread` returns an m*n*3 image, so no colormap is needed.

try to remove the line:

```
aviobj.colormap=cola;
```

and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is due to the encoder of the computer. I restart the computer and the problem is solved. The code I posted is right.